# Find index in sorted array, np.searchsorted() vs. np.where()

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to find the fastest way to return the index of a given element in a sorted array. `np.searchsorted()` seems to be specifically designed for the job. It uses binary search, which should be faster than the generic `np.where()`, which I'm assuming needs to loop through the entire array in O(N). However to my surprise, `np.searchsorted()` takes the same amount of time as `np.where()`, even for large arrays. Here's a MWE:

```py
t_where, t_searchsorted = 0, 0

a = sorted(np.random.uniform(0, 1, 10000))  # sorted array

for i in range(1000):
    
    val = np.random.choice(a)  # randomly select value from array

    t = time.time()
    idx_1 = np.where(a == val)[0][0]
    t_where += (time.time()-t)

    t = time.time()
    idx_2 = np.searchsorted(a, val)
    t_searchsorted += (time.time()-t)
    
print(t_where)         # 0.804 s
print(t_searchsorted)  # 0.793 s
```

**EDIT:** As @Warren Weckesser explained in his [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66989085/5599647), the issue was that `sorted()` would convert my numpy array into a python list, and `np.searchsorted()` was converting it back into a numpy array in O(N). For those who might be wondering, the equivalent of `np.searchsorted()` for python lists is [`bisect.bisect_left()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html). Here's a quick benchmark (reproducing the experiment above):

If `a` is a (sorted) python list, and `val` is in the list:

```py
idx = a.index(val)                 # takes 100.0 ms
idx = bisect.bisect_left(a, val)   # takes 1.4 ms
```

If `a` is a (sorted) numpy array:

```py
idx = np.where(a, val)         # takes 12.1 ms
idx = np.searchsorted(a, val)  # takes 4.5 ms
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used the Python builtin function [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) to sort the random values, so `a` is a Python list, not a NumPy array.  Internally, `searchsorted` will create a NumPy array from that list, which means copying the list, so the actually complexity is O(n) instead of O(log(n)).  The same is true for using `np.where`: the comparison of the Python list to a `numpy.float64` value will end up converting the list to a NumPy array first.

If you change the creation of `a` to something like

```
a = np.random.uniform(0, 1, 10000)
a.sort()
```

you'll get times that are *much* faster, with relative values that reflect the difference between using `where` and `searchsorted`.

Here's the modified version of your script, followed by its output.

```
import time
import numpy as np


t_where, t_searchsorted = 0, 0

a = np.random.uniform(0, 1, 10000)
a.sort()

for i in range(1000):
    
    val = np.random.choice(a)  # randomly select value from array

    t = time.time()
    idx_1 = np.where(a == val)[0][0]
    t_where += (time.time()-t)

    t = time.time()
    idx_2 = np.searchsorted(a, val)
    t_searchsorted += (time.time()-t)
    
print(t_where)
print(t_searchsorted)
```

Output:

```
0.00879216194152832
0.0038056373596191406
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize that `sorted()` was converting numpy arrays into lists. This sorting was just done for this MWE, however my original code was also using a python list as input. "**searchsorted will create a NumPy array from that list, [...] so the actually complexity is O(n)**": this is my key take-away here, I never realized that using numpy functions on python lists would incur a necessary O(n) conversion step. I'll keep that in mind from now on.